# VUE3 use different v-for for the same component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vuex, getter

I have a **JobComponent.vue** component where I fetch data from a **VUEX Store**. This component is used on two separate pages, first page **Home.vue** and second page **AllJobs.vue**.
In AllJobs.vue I used JobComponent.vue and everything is works fine, it's rendering all the jobs, but, here comes the problem...

In **Home.vue** I want to render only the last 5 jobs, so in store I make a *getter* that slice me only the latest 5 jobs.

How can I use this **latestJobs** from *getters* on the same component?

When I import the component in **Home.vue** page I can't use another *v-for* direct on the component...

[here you can see my project structure and files](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-qdp6uc?file=src/components/JobComponent.vue)

**Home.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="cards-container">
      <JobComponent />
  </div>
</template>
```

**JobComponent.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div v-for="job in allJobs" :key="job.id" class="card">
    <div class="position">{{ job.position }}</div>
    <div class="department">{{ job.department }}</div>
    <div class="location">
      <span class="material-symbols-outlined">location_on</span>
      {{ job.location }}
    </div>
    <span class="material-symbols-outlined right-arrow">arrow_right_alt</span>
    <span @click="deleteJob(job.id)" class="material-symbols-outlined right-arrow">delete</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['fetchJobs', 'deleteJob']),
  },
  computed: mapGetters(['allJobs']),
  created() {
    this.fetchJobs();
  }
}
</script>
```

**store.js (vuex)**

```js
const getters = {
    allJobs: (state) => state.jobs,
    
    latestJobs: (state) => {
        const response = state.jobs.slice(0, 5);

        return response;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component should be as independent as possible from the store. It's role is to display what ever is provided so it could be reused as you want, using props :

#### JobComponent.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="position">{{ position }}</div>
    <div class="department">{{ department }}</div>
    <div class="location">
      <span class="material-symbols-outlined">location_on</span>
        {{ location }}
    </div>
    <span class="material-symbols-outlined right-arrow">arrow_right_alt</span>
    <span @click="$emit('deleteJob', id)" class="material-symbols-outlined right-arrow">delete</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    id: string,
    position: string,
    department: string,
    location: string
  }
}
</script>
```

In this component you only display the provided data, and leave the responsibility of the parent component to choose how many components to display.

#### Home.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="cards-container">
    <JobComponent v-for="job in jobs" :key="job.id" :id="job.id" :position="job.position" :department="job.department" :location="job.location" @delete-job="deleteJob" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchJobs')
  },
  computed: {
    jobs() {
      return this.$store.getters['latestJobs'] // Or allJobs, just make sure your getter returns an array even if no jobs are loaded yet.
    }
  },
  methods: {
    deleteJob() {
      // Your logic for job delete
    }
  }
}
</script>
```